# CASE WHEN labels not applying correctly

Tags: sql

My CASE WHEN categories are not applying correctly. You can see here that it's assigning these tracks a pace value of '1' when their tempos are above 120. I defined in the CASE WHEN statement that '1' is only for tempos below '40'

```
SELECT track_name, tempo, 
    CASE 
         WHEN tempo < '40' THEN '1'
         WHEN tempo >= '40' AND tempo < '50' THEN '2'
         WHEN tempo >= '50' AND tempo < '60' THEN '3'
         WHEN tempo >= '60' AND tempo < '70' THEN '4'
         WHEN tempo >= '70' AND tempo < '80' THEN '5'
         WHEN tempo >= '80' AND tempo < '90' THEN '6'
         WHEN tempo >= '90' AND tempo < '100' THEN '7'
         WHEN tempo >= '100' AND tempo < '110' THEN '8'
         WHEN tempo >= '110' AND tempo < '120' THEN '9'
         WHEN tempo >= '120' AND tempo < '130' THEN '10'
         WHEN tempo >= '130' AND tempo < '140' THEN '11'
         WHEN tempo >= '140' AND tempo < '150' THEN '12'
         ELSE NULL
    END  AS Pace
FROM unpopular_songs 
;
```

[image: this shows the incorrect output]

Comment: Why you compare string literals to a number column? Use number literals instead.

Comment: Are you comparing strings? '120.144' is indead < '40' as '1' comes before '4'. Make sure your column is numeric and you compare with < 40, not < '40'.

Comment: And please tag your request with your DBMS.

Comment: What type of column is tempo?

Comment: I'm attempting to create a ranking system in the pace column. The data type for 'tempo' column is a string. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Yes that is the issue. Always use the appropriate data type. As I said '120.144' < '4', because strings get compared character by character.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to CAST tempo as an unsigned character type but am getting an error

SELECT track_name, CAST(tempo AS UNSIGNED), 
 CASE .....

Comment: Life lesson - store a number as a number, store a string as a string and all will be rosy.