# COUNT by column created with CASE statement

Tags: sql

I'm successfully getting an output for the CASE statement below; however, I want to ultimately get a COUNT of each Pace value, which is what I created in the CASE statement. How can I do that?

```
SELECT tempo, popularity,
    CASE 
         WHEN tempo < 40 THEN '1'
         WHEN tempo >= '40' AND tempo < '50' THEN '2'
         WHEN tempo >= '50' AND tempo < '60' THEN '3'
         WHEN tempo >= '60' AND tempo < '70' THEN '4'
         WHEN tempo >= '70' AND tempo < '80' THEN '5'
         WHEN tempo >= '80' AND tempo < '90' THEN '6'
         WHEN tempo >= '90' AND tempo < '100' THEN '7'
         WHEN tempo >= '100' AND tempo < '110' THEN '8'
         WHEN tempo >= '110' AND tempo < '120' THEN '9'
         WHEN tempo >= '120' AND tempo < '130' THEN '10'
         WHEN tempo >= '130' AND tempo < '140' THEN '11'
         WHEN tempo >= '140' AND tempo < '150' THEN '12'
         WHEN tempo >= '150' AND tempo < '160' THEN '13'
         WHEN tempo >= '160' AND tempo < '170' THEN '14'
         WHEN tempo > '170' THEN '15'
         ELSE NULL
    END AS Pace
FROM unpopular_songs 
;
```

[image]

Comment: FYI, you're going to skip the rows where tempo = 170. You should edit your last WHEN with >= 170.

Comment: Your case is still out of order. Didn't https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73572893/case-when-labels-not-applying-correctly learn you anything?

Answer (score 0):

you can try the nested query approach.

the following outer query can be your outer query and the initial query you have written can be used as the inner query.

```
select pace, count(*) from (<your initial query>) group by pace, order by pace  desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I would avoid sub queries for performance. The below should work

```
SELECT tempo, popularity,
  CASE 
     WHEN tempo < 40 THEN '1'
     WHEN tempo >= '40' AND tempo < '50' THEN '2'
     WHEN tempo >= '50' AND tempo < '60' THEN '3'
     WHEN tempo >= '60' AND tempo < '70' THEN '4'
     WHEN tempo >= '70' AND tempo < '80' THEN '5'
     WHEN tempo >= '80' AND tempo < '90' THEN '6'
     WHEN tempo >= '90' AND tempo < '100' THEN '7'
     WHEN tempo >= '100' AND tempo < '110' THEN '8'
     WHEN tempo >= '110' AND tempo < '120' THEN '9'
     WHEN tempo >= '120' AND tempo < '130' THEN '10'
     WHEN tempo >= '130' AND tempo < '140' THEN '11'
     WHEN tempo >= '140' AND tempo < '150' THEN '12'
     WHEN tempo >= '150' AND tempo < '160' THEN '13'
     WHEN tempo >= '160' AND tempo < '170' THEN '14'
     WHEN tempo > '170' THEN '15'
     ELSE NULL
END AS Pace
INTO #TEMP1
FROM unpopular_songs

SELECT pace, COUNT(Pace) as count
FROM #TEMP1
GROUP BY pace
```

Comment: what is meant by #TEMP1?

Comment: its a temp table, you can give it a more meaningful name like "#unpopularSongs". You can store data into it for further processing which is basically what you want to do :)